# Confusion with ant regex at the time of filename selector

Tags: java, regex, ant, antbuilder

I am trying to select all jars from the current directory. I am getting confused between:

- `**/*.jar`
- `*.jar`

I assumed `*.jar` will work the same as `**/*.jar`. However the following examples are working differently:

```
<path id="master-classpath-common-lib" >
    <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<path id="master-classpath-common-lib" >
    <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

For this case `*.jar` is not working at all.

Can anyone please give some hint on this.

Comment: Is this an actual regex? And what kind of file is this?
If it were regex it seems it would work like this: `.*\.jar`
The star usually means that its possible to have an infinite amount of the character before it. In this case the dot means any character. So .* means any character before .jar is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*.jar` means all the .jar files in only within the base directory, the directory specified in `<fileset dir="${master.classpath}/lib">`. This will not include the files in the subdirectories.

In `**/*.jar`, `**` (used as the directory name) is a special feature, that means all the (nested) subdirectories.

Check out an example with explanation [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns).